# converting Data from amount to percentage sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my query it gets the fields in amount but I want to get them in percentage the total amount for each of the fields instead to be getting it in the amount I want to use the total to get the percentage of each field

```
SELECT O.OFFICENAME LABEL, COUNT(AID) Y 
FROM PAYMENT_REF_TABLE P 
INNER JOIN PROCESSING_OFFICE O ON P.PROCESSINGOFFICE = O.OFFICEID 
WHERE O.OFFICENAME IN ('Abuja Hqrs', 'Ikoyi', 'Alausa', 'Portharcourt', 'Kano') 
GROUP BY O.OFFICENAME
```

[image]

As you can see from the image above are the sum of the amount then I want to change it to percentage for each of the fields

Comment: Percentage of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the percentage of the total, use window functions:

```
SELECT O.OFFICENAME as LABEL, COUNT(AID) as Y,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percentage
FROM PAYMENT_REF_TABLE P INNER JOIN 
     PROCESSING_OFFICE O
     ON P.PROCESSINGOFFICE = O.OFFICEID
WHERE O.OFFICENAME IN ('Abuja Hqrs', 'Ikoyi', 'Alausa', 'Portharcourt', 'Kano')
GROUP BY O.OFFICENAME
```

Comment: it works but it goes almost 10 digits after the decimal point, I don't even want the decimal point at all to help me out. And I did try to add "Visit1percent " but did not work help, please

Comment: @kamalAliyu . . . Either use `round()` or convert to an appropriate `decimal()` type *after* doing the division.